# make animation out of html file in python

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have a list of `html` files and I'm trying to put them together into an animation in `python`. I've tried doing this:

```
htims = [list_of_html_images]
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, htims, repeat_delay=1000)
```

But when I try to save it, I get an error:

```
ValueError: the output must be of type htm or html
```

and the `plt.show()` command gives me nothing.

Is there a good way to make animations out of `HTML` images in `python`?

Comment: Using `ArtistAnimation` you may produce an animation of matplotlib `Artists`. I don't know what "html images" are, but for sure they are no matplotlib artists. In addition the error cannot come from the code you show, it must happen before that.

Comment: What do you mean with `list_of_html_images`? Can you give an example (with data)?

Comment: I can't write code from the comments, but I exported a bunch of non-matplotlib images that I generated using the google api to html format. I then stored all the files in a list, and now I want to put them together into an animation